# Dynamically generated buttons seem to not fire their commands?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I have a ListBox which is dynamically filled during runtime. It has a `DataType` of `RequirementPreview` which is needed to bind certain properties to triggers, sources and parameters. There is, however, 1 command-binding that needs to trigger a command that is set in the datacontext but has nothing to do with the template datatype.

What I want is that the `Button` fires the 'RevertDelete'-command and sends the `Guid` of the `RequirementPreview` to which the button belongs. As of now, nothing happens when I press the button.

**Xaml:**

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="5" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" ItemsSource="{Binding Requirements}" SelectionMode="Extended">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
          <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectionChanged}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDeleted}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
         <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
      </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myModels:RequirementPreview}">
            <Grid>
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

               <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
               <Button Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" Visibility="{Binding IsDeleted, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" 
                                        Command="{Binding RevertDelete}" CommandParameter="{Binding Guid}" Height="10" Width="10"/>
            </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Xaml.cs:**

```
    [Dependency]
    public IMainViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return this.DataContext as IMainViewModel; }
        set { this.DataContext = value; }
    }
```

**Edit:**
Tried messing around with the databinding;

```
Command="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.PreviousData}, Path=RevertDelete}"

Command="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=RevertDelete}"

Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=RevertDelete}
```

Neither made a difference.

Comment: If `RevertDelete` is not a part of `RequirementPreview` type which acts as a data context for the template, you'll need to use [relative source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource(v=vs.110).aspx) binding to set command correctly.

Comment: @icebat already figured that was the way to go, but I wasn't sure if and how to set it up correctly. I'll go through the article you mentioned. If you can post an example as answer I can give you the credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `RevertDelete` command is not a part of `RequirementPreview` type which works as a data context for the template. You'll need to use [relative source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource(v=vs.110).aspx) binding for this command:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.RevertDelete, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding Guid}" />
```

Comment: Yes, that is the one I needed :^) As the answer shows I've been messing around for a while now, but I wouldn't have figured out I'd need to list the type as Listbox on my own.. Thanks for the help !

Comment: @Ciphra, cheers! 

`Window` would work as well if it has the same DataContext. In any case you need to specify `DataContext.RevertDelete` in the binding because view model owns the command, not control itself.

Comment: ahh, that's where I went wrong. I was about to try removing the `Datacontext.` in front of the `RevertDelete` because I deemed it obsolete (because the default binding path is the datacontext) but I suppose you already answered how that would turn out :p